# How to assign relationship and fetch data using array field in laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

There are two models: Restaurant and Category

```
Restaurant{
  '_id' : 12345678
  'name' : "xyz",
  'abstract' : "awdwadawdawdawd",
  'category': [1,2,3,4] //category ids
}

Category{
  '_id' : 1,
  'name' : 'PQR'
}
```

How can I assign relationship and fetch all the categories using that array field (category) of Restaurant in laravel 5.3 and Database is mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure about your DB structure, but I think it would be better to create a new pivot table to store the categories of each restaurant in a different row like this:

```
id | restaurant_id | category_id
1  | 23            | 3
2  | 23            | 5
3  | 25            | 4
```

As a convention the table should be named 'category_restaurant'

This would be a many to many relationship in laravel.

```
class Restaurant
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }
}

class Category
{
    public function restaurants()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Restaurant::class);
    }
}
```

Then in your code you can get the ids of a restaurant in this way:

```
$restaurant = Restaurant::find(1);
$categories = $restaurant->categories;
```

Comment: Here is the documentation about it: [Many to many relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't notice the Mongodb part. Not sure how to implement it in the Mongo.

Comment: Yes! I know this but I wanted to know how can I implement this using mongodb array field @isa424